# TLS Ghana failed to scan one of my UK visa application documents

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, applications

I submitted my UK visa documents to be scanned when I went for my appointment at the visa application center, TLSContact. Three days later, I received an email from the UK visa decision center saying they had not received my TB test certificate, and I should book an appointment and provide the certificate within 10 working days. I had already submitted it along with my other documents for scanning when I went for my visa appointment. I am not sure what to do now, as I do not know if that is the only document they did not receive.

I contacted TLSContact Ghana, and they said they would respond to me within 3 working days. What should I do now?

Comment: Has it been 3 days?

Comment: What about booking an appointment and providing TB certificate? It might be easier?

Comment: I would book an appointment and take *all* my documents with me

Comment: OP's wording is unclear, but the email is instructing them to book a **TB test appointment**, which is unnecessary since they already have a certificate.

Answer (score 3):

When a caseworker emails to request further documents, they will request *all* missing documents at once. Additionally, they will not bother to make the request unless the missing document is all that is needed to grant you a visa.

Hence, this email is likely good news: follow the instructions on the email, and submit your TB certificate as soon as possible, and you will likely receive a decision shortly.

Do not bother with contacting TLSContact, everything is out of their hands now.